# How does an app know, if GPS is faked?

Tags: gps, geolocation, developer-options

I have heard it is possible to simulate a GPS location with a developer option. 
However people get banned from Pokémon go, if they fake their location.

Is this because an app knows, when it's a simulated location or did the people just fake it bad enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app can detect when mock locations are enabled. It's quite simple to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6880232/4107809.

Comment: It's not simple, if there is an app hiding the fact that another app is mocking a location (like some xposed modules, MockMockLocations and Hide Mock Location)

Comment: Enabled != using. But I think the app dev don't care and ban in such case. "normal users" don't even know about developer options