# FakeGPS apps on android are not affecting on other apps

Tags: linux, gps, geolocation

I downloaded some fakeGPS app. enabled mock location (developer options) but some app won't take the fake location. For example tiner.

The above solutions did not work for me because I was testing on an Android device with the latest Google Play Services version.

I'm using a linux laptop, so I cannot use all kinds of apps for PC and Mac which you then connect to your android device with a usb cable.

I've also tried using VPN + fakeGPS to the same location - but that didn't work as well.

Is there other solution for `debian user + android user` (pixel 7, latest android version)?

Comment: This question has been cross posted also to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87587/26881

Comment: You may want to read: [How does an app know, if GPS is faked?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/151241/3573) and [How fake gps works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/98027/3573). Also be aware of [How to spoof NMEA sentences on physical Android 8.1 phone for apps like WeChat?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/238758/3573)

Comment: @MorrisonChang, there was no remedy. What can I do?

Comment: There may be no solution which fits your requirements for running on a mobile device. Theoretically a [virtual space app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223785/3573) with a VPN could fake out the NMEA strings/Location data but I'm not aware of a working example. Such a thing would get complicated quickly as apps can check for user movement/location change activity and how does a real location gets translated to a fake lat/long by the virtual space app. Realize that 'faking location' is under the same premise as a bot farm so both Google and app publishers will apply checks.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks, but solutions exist for PC an Mac. Just not for Debian. https://drfone.wondershare.com/virtual-location-changer.html

Comment: Products that have a income means they will keep up the cat-and-mouse game with location centric apps like Pokemon Go. As to how successful, I would check reddit group: https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonGoSpoofing/ . Other apps may get benefits if detection is done by Google Service or apply similar methods on their own backend like Niantic.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Do you think you can help me find a debian solution as well? Maybe free trail ?